# Why is the "lazy_build" feature in Moose discouraged?

Tags: perl, moose

The documentation for the `lazy_build` feature in Moose has this to say:

> **Note that use of this feature is strongly discouraged.** Some documentation used to encourage use of this feature as a best practice, but we have changed our minds.

However, it does not explain what the reasoning for this is, and either my google-fu is terrible or there is no public explanation for why this is discouraged.

What's the problem with `lazy_build` that makes it discouraged today?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is in [Moose::Manual::BestPractices](https://metacpan.org/dist/Moose/view/lib/Moose/Manual/BestPractices.pod#Avoid-lazy_build):

> **Avoid lazy_build**
>
> As described above, you rarely actually need a clearer or a predicate. `lazy_build` adds both to your public API, which exposes you to use cases that you must now test for. It's much better to avoid adding them until you really need them - use explicit `lazy` and `builder` options instead.

So what it's saying is that instead of using the property:

```
has attribute => (
  ...,
  lazy_build => 1, # creates a builder called _build_attribute
);
```

You should instead be more explicit:

```
has attribute => (
  ...,
  lazy => 1,
  builder => '_build_attribute',
);
```

As that doesn't implicitly add `clearer` and `predicate` methods.